# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module nextjs Vercel

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, vercel

Hi I need some help with deploying my nextjs project to Vercel
I am using emails-com to create a contact that work perfectly locally but I get a build fail on Vercel
When I import emailjs-com like this:
`import emailjs from "emailjs-com";`
It doesn't work locally I get
`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`
but then I use this `var emailjs = require("emailjs-com");`then it works locally but then I get a build error
`Type error: Cannot find module 'emailjs-com' or its corresponding type declarations.`

my code:

```
import tw from "twin.macro";
import styled from "styled-components";
import emailjs from "emailjs-com";

const FormZ = () => {
 //  var emailjs = require("emailjs-com");
  
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("Send");
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState("");
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  var service_id = "*********";
  var template_id = "********";
  var user_id = "***********";
  var template_params = {
    userEmail: userEmail,
    subject: title,
    title: title,
    message: msg,
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setStatus("Sending...");
    emailjs.send(service_id, template_id, template_params, user_id).then(
      function (response) {
        console.log("SUCCESS!", response.status, response.text);
        setStatus("Sent");
      },
      function (err) {
        console.log("FAILED...", err);
        setStatus("error in form");
      }
    );
  };
```

I appreciate all the help